# Query SQL on Orientdb with append and substring

Tags: orientdb

I need to retrieve the country from a number having a table with international_prefix and local_prefix like image.

[image]

This is a test that I've made but unfortunately won't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM core_phone_prefix
WHERE (("+393925559000").asString()).left(international_prefix.append(local_prefix).length()) = international_prefix.append(local_prefix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this query

```
select country from( 
    select number.left(international_prefix.append(local_prefix).length()) as a, international_prefix.append(local_prefix) as b, country from (
        select international_prefix, "+393925559000" as number, country, local_prefix from core_phone_prefix
    )
) where a = b
```

**UPDATED**

You can insert two index, one on the field *international_prefix* (NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX) and one on the field *local_prefix* (NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX )

You can use this query

```
select expand($a) from (select "+393925559000" as number from core_phone_prefix limit 1)
    let $a=(select from core_phone_prefix WHERE international_prefix = $parent.current.number.left(international_prefix.length()) 
            and local_prefix = $parent.current.number.subString(international_prefix.length(),international_prefix.append(local_prefix).length())) limit -1
```

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

With this one I compare only the prefix

```
select distinct(country) as country from(select international_prefix, "+393925559000" as number, country, local_prefix from core_phone_prefix) where international_prefix=number.subString(0,international_prefix.length())
```

Instead, with this one I compare the international_prefix + the local_prefix with the international_prefix and the local_prefix of the number

```
select country as country from(select international_prefix, "+393925559000" as number, country, local_prefix from core_phone_prefix) where international_prefix.append(local_prefix)=number.subString(0,international_prefix.append(local_prefix).length())
```

Hope it helps,

Let me know

Comment: This is something I've already tried.

Query returned a result set with more than 10000 records. Check if you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM. :(

Comment: There are 120,437 records.